# Contour integral $\int_{|z|=1}\exp(1/z)\sin(1/z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

Evaluate the contour integral $$\int_{|z|=1}\exp(1/z)\sin(1/z)\,dz$$ along the circle $|z|=1$ counterclockwise once.

The singularities are $\dfrac1{\pi k},k\in\mathbb{Z}$ plus the limit point $0$. So I can't apply the residue theorem. Any other alternative?

Comment: See also the very similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124477/help-calculating-int-c-e-1-z-sin1-zdz-over-the-unit-circle

Comment: @IanMallett: It is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: How is $1/\pi $ a singularity? Similarly the rest?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\vert z \vert = 1 \implies \vert 1/z \vert = 1$. Hence, setting $w=1/z$, we get that
\begin{align}
\int_{\vert z \vert = 1} \exp(1/z) \sin(1/z) dz & = \overbrace{\underbrace{\int_{\vert w \vert = 1} \exp(w) \sin(w) \dfrac{dw}{w^2}}_{\text{by change in orientation of integral}}}^{\text{Negative sign gets cancelled}}\\
& = \int_{\vert w \vert = 1} \dfrac{\left(1+ \mathcal{O}(w)\right)(1+\mathcal{O}(w^2))}w dw = 2 \pi i
\end{align}

Comment: Does the orientation of the integral flip since w=1/z is a Möbius transformation that changes orientation?

Comment: @IanMallett: it does, but that is countered by the sign of $\mathrm{d}\frac1w=-\frac1{w^2}\mathrm{d}w$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\exp(1/z)\sin(1/z)\,\dd z}
&=\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over 2\ic}\bracks{%
\exp\pars{1 + \ic \over z}- \exp\pars{1 - \ic \over z}}\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=2\pi\ic\,{\pars{1 + \ic} - \pars{1 - \ic} \over 2\ic}
=\color{#66f}{\Large 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}